# How to perform RAG with date filter in MongoDB - Python?

Tags: python, mongodb, fastapi, langchain

I could perform RAG with Python using Langchain, but I couldn't find docs to perform RAG along with date range filter.

But, I have a hint - It should be done with aggregate with filter and vector search

Please let me know what other opts available!

I tried using the Langchain but I couldn't attain.